# Python: For a give connectivity find its branch with a specific start index

Tags: python, tree, branch

Here is my question, ethane with bond connectivity (1H-2H-3H)-4C-5C-(6H-7H-8H)
If start from 4, but pass the 5 and its branch. I expect it return [1,2,3]
Or more complicate, propane (1H-2H-3H)-4C-5C-(6H-7H)-8C-(9H-10H-11H)
Start from 4 and also pass 5, I expect it return [1,2,3]

```
def det_connectivity(total_bond, atom_index, pass_idx):
   Have no idea...

total_bond = [(1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (5,7), (5,8)] #Ethane
ans = connectivity(total_bond = total_bond , atom_index = 4, pass_idx = 5)
ans = [1,2,3]
total_bond = [(1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (5,7), (5,8), (8,9), (8,10), (8,11)] #Propane
ans = connectivity(total_bond = total_bond , atom_index = 4, pass_idx = 5)
ans = [1,2,3]
```

Thank you

Comment: What would be the output for these examples when the pass index is 8 instead of 5?

Comment: Good question... In my application, these index are a rotor of the molecule so it will not be  a leaf.  But I think it would be 1-7 except 8!?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a recursive function that is used by the `det_connectivity` function. Python’s `set` type is very convenient to collect the indices of the atoms.

```py
def det_connectivity(total_bond, atom_index, pass_idx):
    atom_set = bond_search(total_bond, {atom_index}, {atom_index, pass_idx})
    return sorted(atom_set - {atom_index, pass_idx})

def bond_search(total_bond, neighbors, visited):
    found = set()
    for pair in total_bond:
        if pair[0] in neighbors and pair[1] not in visited:
            found.add(pair[1])
        elif pair[1] in neighbors and pair[0] not in visited:
            found.add(pair[0])
    if not found:
        return visited
    else:
        return bond_search(total_bond, found, visited | found)

total_bond = [(1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (5,7), (5,8)] #Ethane
ans = det_connectivity(total_bond, atom_index = 4, pass_idx = 5)
print (ans)

total_bond = [(1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (5,7), (5,8), (8,9), (8,10), (8,11)] #Propane
ans = det_connectivity(total_bond, atom_index = 4, pass_idx = 5)
print (ans)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it!!